# IOS/Autolayout: Set constraints for tableview

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to set the constraints for a tableview.  However, I cannot CTRL-Drag from the tableview to the view controller and when I select the tableview, the autlayout controls are inactive.  Can anyone suggest the proper way to apply auto layout so that a tableview acts correctly for all screen sizes?

storyboard
[image]

Pin in autolayout
[image]

Comment: can not CTRL-Drag what? whats your question?

Comment: ctrl drag from tableview to superview and see option to set constraints.  Only see delegate option.  Question is how to set auto layout constraints for tableview so that it displays properly for all screen sizes. As of now, I can't see how to set any constraints at all in storyboard.

Comment: Click the light red imaginary line in the Pin, then you can set constraint.

Comment: If you mean the four lines up, down left and right they are faint and inactive.  Don't respond when I click on them.

Comment: i saw your controller is tableview controller. so the tableview in it is constrainted. you no need do again.

Comment: In this case, the tableView is the root view of the viewController. It looks like you're using a UITableViewController. In which case, you don't need to add any constraints.
If you want more control over the layout, then you need to use a standard UIViewController and add a UITableView manually.